# ST2 ListItem setHtml can't get the value of the sub-node

Tags: sencha-touch-2, dataview, listitem

I have two model 'Statuses' belongTo:'User',I'm leaning the examples of sencha touch 2 named touchtweets.
here is my json file

```
{
"statuses" : [{
    "text" : "test",
    "user" : {
        "name" : foo,
              }
             }]
}
```

the official documentation say 'when the record is updated, get the text configuration, and
  call `setText` with the 'text' field of the record.but I'm try setHtml:'user.name' it did'nt work I can't understand.
Here is my view code,

```
Ext.define('Demo.view.StatusesListItem', {
extend : 'Ext.dataview.component.ListItem',
xtype : 'statuseslistitem',
requires : ['Demo.view.StatusesListItemText', 'Ext.Img'],

config : {
    dataMap : {
        getText : {
            setHtml : 'text',        //work well
        },
        getUserName : {
            setHtml : 'user.name',   //didn't work
        }
    },
    userName : {
        cls : 'username'
    },
    text : {
        cls : 'text'
    },
    layout : {
        type : 'vbox'
    }
},
applyUserName : function(config) {
    console.log(Ext.factory(config, Ext.Component, this.getUserName()))
    return Ext.factory(config, Ext.Component, this.getUserName());
},
applyText : function(config) {
    return Ext.factory(config, Sin.view.StatusesListItemText, this.getText());
},
updateTpl : Ext.emptyFn,

});  

Ext.define('Demo.view.StatusesListItemText', {
extend : 'Ext.Component',

applyHtml : function(html) {
    html = html.replace(/(http:\/\/[^\s]*)/g, "<a class=\"link\"       target=\"_blank\" href=\"$1\">$1</a>");
    return html;
}
});
```

setHtml can't get the value of the sub-nodeuse

Anyone can help me? Thx your time

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible.

A hack to get around it would be to set the value of `getUserName` to `user` and then change your `applyUserName` method to access the `name` property.

```
applyUserName : function(config) {
    var name = config.name;

    return Ext.factory(name, Ext.Component, this.getUserName());
}
```

Comment: Thx ,but I don't understand,I have change my code                               dataMap : {
 getUserName : {
  setHtml : 'user',
        },
 },      and applyUserName function  but in console.log the config.name return undefined ,can you help me